# Parse elfeed's entry cl-struct

Tags: hooks, elfeed

I'm trying to display notifications using elfeed's hook and [alert](https://github.com/jwiegley/alert). This works:

```lisp
(add-hook 'elfeed-new-entry-hook
          (lambda (entry)
            (alert (prin1-to-string (elfeed-entry-content entry))
                   :severity 'high)))
```

But it only displays a "raw" cl-struct. I can't figure out how to parse it properly. This stops working:

```lisp
(add-hook 'elfeed-new-entry-hook
          (lambda (entry)
            (alert (prin1-to-string (elfeed-deref (elfeed-entry-content entry)))
                   :title (prin1-to-string (elfeed-entry-feed-id entry))
                   :severity 'high)))
```